# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string --> MONTH(columnName) = 09

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Running the following query I am getting an error:

```
select X 
from TABLE_ONE 
where COLUMN_ONE_UID = 525
  and COLUMN_TWO_UID = 54 
  and YEAR(X) = 2019
  and MONTH(X) = 09
order by SEQUENCE_NO
```

**Error:**

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**The X column:**

[image: x]

How can I get the query to return all rows where the month is 09 and the year is 2019?

Comment: Why you're storing dates as strings in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stored as "date" value as a string.  This is a really bad format.

So, to answer your question, use string functions:

```
select X
from DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
where DASHBOARD_OBJECT_SERIES_UID = 525 and
      DASHBOARD_OBJECT_UID = 54 and
      X like '%-09-2019;
order by SEQUENCE_NO;
```

Then work on fixing the data so `X` is stored using the correct type:

```
update DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
    set X = try_convert(concat(right(X, 4), substring(X, 4, 2), left(X, 2)));

alter table DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
    alter column X date;
```

Comment: ah, didn't think of doing it that way. It's not my software so I have to do with the date being in that format.

Comment: 1st Why you're using `TRY_CONVERT()` there? 2nd your query will throw an error near `RIGHT()`.

Comment: @sami . . . This uses `TRY_CONVERT() `just in case some of the values are not correct dates.  The error was the lack of `CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to fix the data type of your column, so things becomes easy:

```
UPDATE DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
SET X = CONCAT(RIGHT(X, 4), SUBSTRING(X, 3, 4), LEFT(X, 2));

ALTER TABLE DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
ALTER COLUMN X DATE;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=735acc3bfa3a7143586081ba77b01638)**

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all your values are in the format `dd-MM-yyyy` the you could do this:

```
SELECT X
FROM DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA
WHERE DASHBOARD_OBJECT_SERIES_UID = 525
  AND DASHBOARD_OBJECT_UID = 54
  AND TRY_CONVERT(date,X, 105) >= '20190901'
  AND TRY_CONVERT(date,X, 105) < '20191001'
ORDER BY SEQUENCE_NO; --Seems odd, considering it's not in the SELECT
```

but like others have said, you should really be storing your dates as a date/time datatype in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff suggestion is correct.

I know that you will not update your table definition and not updating data also.

Because there may be possibilities that you are importing data from different sources in DASHBOARD_OBJECT_DATA table.

Please check below example query which will help you to resolve your error.

```
SELECT
    *
    INTO #tblDate
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'11/12/2019 15:12:20') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'01/01/2019 15:12:20') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'13/12/2001 15:12:20') AS Xdate UNION ALL  -- Not correct date
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'TEST') AS Xdate UNION ALL  -- Not date data
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-05-04 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-04-05 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-09-05 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-09-20 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-09-22 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-09-25 05:08:09') AS Xdate UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2019-02-29 21:28:09') AS Xdate -- Not correct date
) X

SELECT 
    t.XDate 
FROM #tblDate t

SELECT 
    t.XDate 
FROM #tblDate t
WHERE CASE WHEN ISDATE(t.XDate) = 1 THEN CAST(t.XDate AS DATE) ELSE '1900-01-01' END >= '2019-09-01' --September Month 1st Day
AND CASE WHEN ISDATE(t.XDate) = 1 THEN CAST(t.XDate AS DATE) ELSE '1900-01-01' END < '2019-10-01' --October Month 1st Day
```

Check this [link](https://rextester.com/OGHQL86388) for result.

***Note***: This will create some performance issue if data is in millions because of **CASE WHEN** statement checking for each and every record.